# Armazenar quantidade de valores em um txt PHP

Tags: php, txt

Possuo as informações abaixo em um arquivo `txt`.

```
500038;204932;61312;FTE GAV EDIT LACAVA TOTAL LARGXALTX15 GAV. NORMAL;LACA BLU FOSCO#996#335;5;78101922;xxxxxxx;0204932005
500038;204932;61312;FTE GAV EDIT LACAVA TOTAL LARGXALTX15 GAV. NORMAL;LACA BLU FOSCO#696#166;12;xxxxxxx;0204932012
100398;204932;50384;CJTO OPC LAT DIR/ESQ ARMARIO 30XALTXPROF;MDF BP LEGGERO#1040#340;74;78728780;xxxxxxx;0204932074
100398;204932;50385;CJTO OPC BASE SUP/INF RETA ARM LARGX30XPROF;MDF BP LEGGERO#769#340;71;78728777;xxxxxxx;0204932071
100398;204932;61108;FTE GAV EDIT ALCA LARGXALTX18 GAV. QUAD;LEGGERO#696#164;77;78728783;xxxxxxx;0204932077
100398;204932;50057;PAI OPC EDIT LARGXALTX15;LEGGERO#2610#100;39;78728745;xxxxxxx;0204932039
```

Peguei essas informações e armazenei em um `array`.

Após isso peguei somente o número dos pedidos e armazenei em outro `array`.

```
$file_name = "IMP.txt";

$file = fopen("ArquivoOrig/".$file_name, "r") or die ("Arquivo não encontrado!");
$file_output = fopen("ArquivoImp/Output_".$file_name, "w") or die ("Arquivo não criado!");

    while(!feof($file)){    
      $strAnalise =  fgets($file);
      $strAnaliseArray = explode(";", $strAnalise);
    if(trim($strAnaliseArray[7]) != ''){
        $ArrayChaveNome[$strAnaliseArray[1]] = trim($strAnaliseArray[7]);
    }
    $strArrayDados[] = $strAnaliseArray;
}

foreach ($strArrayDados as $key => $value) {
    if(trim($value[7]) == ''){
        if(array_key_exists($value[1], $ArrayChaveNome)){
            $strArrayDados[$key][7]= $ArrayChaveNome[$value[1]];
        }
    }
}

for ($i=0; $i < count($strArrayDados); $i++) { 
    $arrayTemp[$i] = $strArrayDados[$i][0];
}

var_dump($arrayValor);

//Monta arquivo
foreach ($strArrayDados as $key => $value) {
    $dataAtual = date('dmY');
    fwrite($file_output, $dataAtual.";");
    $resultPontoVirgulaToTxt = implode(";", $value);
    fwrite($file_output, $resultPontoVirgulaToTxt);

}

fclose($file_output);
fclose($file);
```

Usei a funçao `array_count_values` para contar os números de pedidos, sendo que possue 2 pedidos com o número `500038` e 4 pedidos com o número `100398`.

```
$arrayValor = array_count_values($arrayTemp);
```

Retorno:

```
Array
(
    [500038] => 2
    [100398] => 4
)
```

Agora a pergunta é, como eu coloco esses valores ao lado do número de pedido de forma dinâmica, **pois os números de pedidos podem váriar e a quantidade também.** Isso é o que tem que estar no `txt`, não imprimir na tela.

Como preciso que fique:

```
2;500038;204932;61312;FTE GAV EDIT LACAVA TOTAL LARGXALTX15 GAV. NORMAL;LACA BLU FOSCO#996#335;5;78101922;xxxxxxx;0204932005
2;500038;204932;61312;FTE GAV EDIT LACAVA TOTAL LARGXALTX15 GAV. NORMAL;LACA BLU FOSCO#696#166;12;xxxxxxx;0204932012
4;100398;204932;50384;CJTO OPC LAT DIR/ESQ ARMARIO 30XALTXPROF;MDF BP LEGGERO#1040#340;74;78728780;xxxxxxx;0204932074
4;100398;204932;50385;CJTO OPC BASE SUP/INF RETA ARM LARGX30XPROF;MDF BP LEGGERO#769#340;71;78728777;xxxxxxx;0204932071
4;100398;204932;61108;FTE GAV EDIT ALCA LARGXALTX18 GAV. QUAD;LEGGERO#696#164;77;78728783;xxxxxxx;0204932077
4;100398;204932;50057;PAI OPC EDIT LARGXALTX15;LEGGERO#2610#100;39;78728745;xxxxxxx;0204932039
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu valor saiu um pouco diferente do que citou, aqui apareceu assim:

```
array(2) {
  ["500038;204932"]=>
  int(2)
  ["100398;204932"]=>
  int(4)
}
```

Acho que tem várias maneiras de fazer isto, uma que pode usar é o `explode` como limitador, ou um simples `str_replace`:

```
<?php
$valoresStr = '500038;204932
500038;204932
100398;204932
100398;204932
100398;204932
100398;204932';

$arrayTemp = explode(chr(10), trim($valoresStr));

$arrayValores = array_count_values($arrayTemp);

var_dump($arrayValores);

foreach ($arrayValores as $valor => $soma) {
    $valoresStr = str_replace($valor, $soma . ';' . $valor, $valoresStr);
}

echo PHP_EOL;

echo $valoresStr;
```

Veja que troquei `$valor` por `$soma . ';' . $valor`, isso quer dizer que adicione o prefixo como sendo o valor da soma, claro que isto irá funcionar para o seu exemplo, agora não sei afirmar se haverá variações após o `;` disto `500038;204932`, por exemplo isto `500038;2000001`

Exemplo online: http://ideone.com/wDGpXc

Comment: Antes de armazenar já dei um `explode` nos delimitadores que são `;`. Esqueci de mencionar. Por isso que já saiu assim `Array
(
    [500038] => 2
    [100398] => 4
)`

Comment: @Kevin.F posta então o código na pergunta de maneira que possamos entender, por favor

Comment: Sua resposta não deu a resposta para mim mas eu consegui fazer, sua resposta clareou as coisas.

Comment: @Kevin.F não deu certo porque o exemplo na sua pergunta esta incompleto, se colocar completo eu conseguirei formular da maneira que você precisa. Teu exemplo atualizado continua saindo diferente

Comment: Então, coloquei todo meu código e toda as informações que possui o `txt` vê se agora está melhor para entender.

Comment: @Kevin.F agora ficou melhor, vou tentar ajustar o exemplo.